# Going through a Variable that contains HTML to check for specific words

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Quill Editor, which is basically a Box like in SO where you type in text and get HTML out.
I store that HTML in a variable. Now my Website has a List of Tags (certain keywords) of brands and categories.

I would like a functionality to see if a Tag is inside that HTML.
For example, my Author types `The new Nike Store is open now` I would need the `Nike` to be a Tag. It can be a span with a certain class.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I want to check before publishing as live detection is not needed.

My Solution for now:

I didn´t implement it yet, but I think I would try to check every word inside my tag list before going to the next and wrapping it in the needed HTML Tags if the word is a Tag. But this could get messy to code because of all the other stuff like the other HTML Tags that get generated through the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the author types just plain text, you can use a regular expression to search for tag words (or phrases) and replace the phrase in the HTML with that phrase, surrounded in a `span` with your new class:

```js
const input = 'The new Nike Store is open now';
const htmlStr = input.replace(/\bnike\b/gi, `<span class="tag">$&</span>`);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

```css
.tag {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Or, for dynamic tags, create the pattern dynamically:

```js
const input = 'The new Nike Store is open now';
const tags = ['nike', 'open'];
const pattern = new RegExp(tags.join('|'), 'gi');
const htmlStr = input.replace(pattern, `<span class="tag">$&</span>`);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

```css
.tag {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

(if the tags can contain characters with a special meaning in a regular expression, [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) them first before passing to `new RegExp`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far this is defenetly helpful, one thing I need to modify is probably the Quill API to get the Index Location of the Text im replacing with the Tag, an im 99% sure that there is no way for me to get the non html String Version of the content